# Hash Set giving error when comparing an input

Tags: java, string, hashset

Trying to check a password against values in a hash set.  The error appears to be in the myset.contains but cant see why.

```
Set<String> myset = new HashSet<>();
myset.add("Apples");
myset.add("Bananas");

String inputPass;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Fruit?: ");
inputPass = input.nextLine();

if (inputPass.equals(myset.contains)) {
    // Lecturer.printMe();
    System.out.println("Welcome");
}
else {
    System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
}
```

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: And what is the actual error?

Comment: Code would not compile error. Ok now as Tim answer works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use of [`Set#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) does not look right to me.  Try using this version:

```
if (myset.contains(inputPass)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome");
}
else {
    System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"contains" is a method, not a field. Also, it accepts an instance of T (in this case, a String) as a parameter.